# autogenerate javascript from mysql

Tags: bash, mysql, javascript

I have a site where I can upload images with some info (startdate, enddate, duration, url)

I want to make a SlideShow that choose those pictures that is > $startdate && < $enddate. And I want each picture to be displayed as long as I've set it to in the value $duration.
My Javascript so far is like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showPic1(){
$('#test').html("<img src=\"$url" width=" 400 " height=" 300 ">");
setTimeout(showPic2, $dur);}

function showPic2(){
$('#test').html("<img src=\"$url" width=" 400 " height=" 300 ">");
setTimeout(showPic1, 9000);}

showPic1();
</script>
<div id="test"><img src='http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/bild1.jpg' width='400' height='300'></div>
```

Pretty simple..
But how can I autogenerate this javascriptcode with exemple bash-script from a database?!

Any Idéas?

Comment: Ehmmm... how is this related to Ubuntu? You may wish to check a different place where to ask for questions like this. Maybe a good place could be http://stackoverflow.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java

Answer (score 0):

You could use the -execute switch  `mysql -e`

```
foo=`mysql -u user_name_here -p password_here -s -N -e "SELECT id FROM the.host WHERE name='$the_url'"`
echo $foo
echo "<some>$foo<\/some>" >> /file/path/to_name_of_output.js
```

But why not use PHP or PERL?